# Importing Android project from GitHub and Migrate to Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am a Java EE Developer and I haven't experience with android, but for one exam in univercity I have got an android task. So I have found something in GitHub, that will help me, but I can't import it in my Android Studio.

Here is the project for who I mentioned - [GitHub](https://github.com/charlesarmitage/battleship-project)

When I import the project I receive the following isuues:
[image]

And the look when the project is expanded:
[image]

I will be greatfull for some guidelines how can I import the project.
Previously thanks for the time spend for my issue.

Comment: Did your net connection was On during the sync of gradle?

Comment: Yes it is. My connection is on

Comment: And do you have GitHub installed in your system and check whether you have integrated Github with Android Studio.

Comment: Yes I've got GitHub, I import the project but I can't rin the project because of gradle migration is not done, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: add root as I suggested in the answer below and your problem will be solved.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't works. Thanks for the help, I'm done with my issue. I create a project with own strength and I'm ready for the exam.

Comment: Good to hear that ! Glad I could help you. You can atleast upvote or accept my answer incase if any user encounters this same problem might get help from my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press "add root" when the warning message appears.

This will make idea register the "unregistered vcs root", and you can use the git features of IDEA/Android studio. Nothing bad will happen if you do not press "add root", but I suspect you will get the same warning on each startup of android studio/IDEA.